# What is silhouette?

Tags: macos

I have a process called `silhouette` running on 10.13 (apparently the executable file is located in `/usr/libexec/`). It is extremely mysterious, I found no information whatsoever on the Internet regarding this process. Even databases of macOS processes would not mention it.

The CPU load of `silhouette` is extremely low, it would go totally unnoticed if not for one line in the Activity Monitor. It does not seem to establish network connections but I haven’t monitored it enough to be sure.

What is this process and what is it doing?

Comment: Do you mean [silhouette](http://blog.silhouetteamerica.com/2016/09/downloading-and-installing-your-silhouette-software)?

Comment: Oops, yes of course it’s *silhouette* (noun) (and not sLihouette -- I corrected the typo). It’s not related to a software called Silhouette though... I’ve never installed anything named like this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`man silhouette` reports (rather unhelpfully):

> silhouette -- generate local topics on the device.

The daemon is launched by `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.coreparsec.silhouette.plist` which is part of CoreParsec, the private framework that is part of Siri's backend.

`strings /usr/libexec/silhouette` yields a lot of method names related to machine learning: scoring bins, bloom filters, normalization routines, false positives, etc.

Absent further documentation from Apple, it's reasonable to conclude that this daemon is part of Siri's infrastructure.  "Local topics" has a specific meaning in machine learning (usually in context of clustering algorithms), though I'm not sure if it's being used in that context or not.

It is for sure not malware, if that's what you're concerned about.

Comment: Very helpful! Well I was not super concerned but I thought it could be either a) malware (but given the location, the fact it is signed by Apple, has a man page etc.: rather unlikely), or b) some kind of broken legacy software, or c) legit macOS process but the kind of strange stuff nobody really knows what it does and what it sends. Apparently it belongs to c)